# Does signalR backplane shares connections also?

Tags: signalr, signalr-backplane

Does signalR backplane shares the connection information also?

I mean in case of "longpolling" the connect request goes to one server and start server goes to another server then it gives this error 
 "The ConnectionId is in the incorrect format."

I am believing  that this error is coming because the instance on which this request is going does not have any information about this connection id. I am using SQL server backplane but still facing this problem.

We are not supposed to use sticky session in our production environment

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855744/signalr-giving-the-connectionid-is-in-the-incorrect-format-only-after-moving-t

Comment: In the other thread they are talking about having the same machine key. But in my case both the instances of my signalR site are on the same server under one load balancer site. So they are already sharing the same machine.config.
Still I am facing this problem.
Any idea?

Comment: _connect request goes to one server and start server goes to another server_
Can you better explain\fix this part ? Can you try if you get same error using SSE transport ?

Answer (score 1):

No, SignalR doesn't share any information regarding client connect\disconnect over the backplane (for example - server2 is not notified about new client connections on server1)

So the problem is somewhere else...

Comment: If somehow we share the connection information on both the servers, then is it possible that client connect/negotiate with Server1 and poll on Server2 and still it gets the messages from Server2?

Comment: When using backplane, message _broadcasted_ from server is delivered to every client regardless to which server it is connected. That's the purpose of backplane. You don't need to do anything to make it work. That doesn't mean every server knows (or needs to know) about every client connected to every server...

Answer (score 1):

I got the problem. Its machine key issue only.
I had to explicitly add machine key in web.config of my application.
Then it is able to unprotect the token which is generated by another instance of my application.
Now its working fine.